# PHP: Expression regular, sub the "<?" and "?>", how it does?

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match-all

i would to know how match all tag less `"<?"` and `"?>"` 
For example:

```
"<?root?><abcd>"
```

I thought:

```
preg_match_all(/[^(<\?)(\?>)]+/, $str, $match);
```

but rsult is `["root", "abcd"]` instead i wold like to be so `["<abcd>"]`

Thanks'!

Comment: You know what a character class in regex is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<(?!\?).+?(?<!\?)>
```

That should do the trick.

Explanation:

```
<    -- A <
(?!  -- Not followed by: (See link 1 - Positive and Negative Lookahead)
  \? -- A ?
)
.+?  -- As few characters as necessary (See link 2 - Laziness Instead of Greediness)
(?<! -- Not preceded by: (See link 1 - Positive and Negative Lookbehind)
  \? -- A ?
)
>    -- A >
```

1. [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
2. [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

IIRC, you would do this:

```
preg_match_all('/<(?!\?).+?(?<!\?)>/', $str, $match);
```

However, [it isn't a good idea to parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/785745).

Comment: What do "(?!\?)" and ".+?" mean?
Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

I sure hope this is not HTML, but this will match angle bracket surrounded words without question marks in between:

```
/<\w+>/
```

If other than `\w` characters are allowed inside but no question marks:

```
/<[^>?]+>/
```

If question marks are allowed inside but only rejected when adjacent to angle brackets:

```
/<[^?].*?[^?]>/
```

However, the above will have the side effect that `<b>` will not be matched due to minimum length constraint.

Answer (score 0):

That's trivial, but you're approaching it the wrong way. You should be matching what you want rather than not matching what you don't want. To match a tag, use a variation of this:

```
<\w+[^>\?]*>
```

Making it as specific as you need it. As long as `\?` isn't in the set of allowed characters in the tag, it should be fine. Also note that this will match tags with attributes.